# Leaving a Database Connection Open?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, unit-testing, unity-container

My web application has the following class:

```
public class DatabaseProvider {
    private readonly IDbConnection _cn;

    public DatabaseProvider(IDbConnection cn) {
        _cn = cn;
    }

    public void ExecuteNonQuery(string query) {
        // Execute the query
        var cmd = _cn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Where the IDbConnection dependency is declared using the following code (with Microsoft Unity):

```
container.RegisterType<IDbConnection>(new InjectionFactory(c => {
    var cn = new SqlConnection("...");
    cn.Open();
    return cn;
}));
```

This allows me to swap out the connection to SQLite like so:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbConnection>(new InjectionFactory(c => {
    var cn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;");
    cn.Open();
    return cn;
}));
```

I use SQLite when testing and the connection must remain open otherwise the data is lost. Therefore I can't just open and close the connection when needed.

I have always opened the connection to the database when it was needed and was wondering whether this will scale for large applications?

I'd appreciate any advice on how this can be improved. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule in ADO.NET the connection must be closed as soon as possible.

Connections are re-used from connection pool and are scarce resource.

The recommended way to do this is with using () {} construct.

[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28VS.100%29.aspx)

We strongly recommend that you **always close the connection** when you are finished using it so that the **connection will be returned to the pool**. You can do this using either the Close or Dispose methods of the Connection object, or by opening all connections inside **a using statement in C#**, or a Using statement in Visual Basic. Connections that are not explicitly closed might not be added or returned to the pool. For more information, see using Statement (C# Reference) or How to: Dispose of a System Resource (Visual Basic) for Visual Basic.

So, I suggest that you make a interface **IDbProvider** and then make 2 implementations: **SqlServerProvider** and **SQLiteProvider** and handle opening and closing connections inside them. Then use Unity to bind one provider or another.

Comment: Thanks that was roughly what I thought.

Comment: @Petar Repac, could you tell me why you say connections are scarce resource? what doe's it mean? Thanks.

Comment: @dan, the cost in creating a new connection to DB is high (needs to negotiate various details with DB) and because of that .NET keeps a "pool" of already created connections so that your code can reuse one of the connections from the pool instead of always creating a new one. But your code must behave well and after it is done working with DB it must return the connection back into the pool.

Comment: @Petar Repac, thanks for the clarification. So when you say connection creation is costly doesn't that indicate leaving the open connection as is much advisable? My earlier question around 'connections are scares resource' is about that. Again thanks and much appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't open it when you instantiate the connection in unity. But open it when at first use in your code as usual and close it when it's not needed anymore.

This would change your DatabaseProvider

```
public class DatabaseProvider {
    private readonly IDbConnection _cn;

    public DatabaseProvider(IDbConnection cn) {
        _cn = cn;
    }

    public void ExecuteNonQuery(string query) {
        // Execute the query
        try{
           _cn.Open();
           var cmd = _cn.CreateCommand();
           cmd.CommandText = query;
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(ExpectedExceptions){
           //take care of business
        }
        finally{
            _cn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Be aware of the scope that Unity uses to create the instance and the spanned lifetime.
The above solution is not thread-safe, having the same instance on different threads can bring a nice debug-fest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I marked Petar's as the answer since it provided a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this one.

And in my way always check the connection state and when it's open close it.

```
public class DatabaseProvider {
    private readonly IDbConnection _cn;

    public DatabaseProvider(IDbConnection cn) {
        _cn = cn;
    }

    public void ExecuteNonQuery(string query) {

        using(SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand{ Connection = _cn})
        {

            if(_cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
               _cn.Close();

            try
            {
               _cn.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
               // Message Connection Error
            }

            try
            {
               cmd.CommandText = query;
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Message Query Error
            }
            finally
            {
                _cn.Close();  // Connection close
            }

        }


    }
}
```